# C# WinScp Assemblies - weird encoded chars in file name

Tags: c#, encoding, winscp

I have a file which I can't rename, that has weird chars in it's name.
When trying to download it with Session.GetFiles it gets stuck, downloads the file with it's name and extension, but without any data inside (size is 0kb) while the original file isn't empty and it's size is bigger than 0kb.
After 30 minutes - 174 hours (yes, over 1 week) I get an exception that copying files from remote side failed. Thia file will also fail downloading with the WinScp GUI, but with another FTP guis such as FlashFXP it downloads successfully.
Is there any way that WinScp can support a wider encoding system?
Thank You.

Comment: Show us a log file from WinSCP GUI as well as FlashFXP.

Comment: Where is the winscp log file located?

Comment: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging